# How to execute AT Commands in adb shell

Tags: android

I just like to know how to execute AT Commands in adb shell for android devices.

Example:

```
AT+CGMI ---- (Execution command returns the device manufacturer identification code)
```

Comment: I don't think you can. AT commands are sent over some internal bus to some hardware module, e.g. the telephone modem chip. AT is the message format / communication protocol, it's nothing you can execute directly in a shell.